# issue in firefox with commenting out html

Tags: html, comments

I have an issue in firefox and not in IE, didn't think I'd hear myself say that one, where if I have an commented section in my html like so:

```
<!--------------form--------------->
<div id='form'>
etc etc.
</div>

<!------------main content----------------->
```

The area in between the two comment tags is being completely struck out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firefox 3 html commenting issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312080/firefox-3-html-commenting-issue)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the dashes inside the comments, it will work then. I’ve forgotten the exact rule but basically *double dashes inside comments are not allowed* and cause problems.

```
<!-- form -->
<div id='form'>
etc etc.
</div>

<!-- main content -->
```

Read the [relevant section](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-comments) in the standard.

**tl;dr: Firefox is right, MSIE is broken.**

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the extra `-`s. (ie, keep `<!--` and `-->`, but change the rest to spaces or something.)