# Firefox 3 html commenting issue

Tags: html, firefox, xhtml

So I have a site where there are a lot of places where html comments are written as

I noticed that when you write:

```
            <div>hello</div>
            <!-- COMMENT --------------- //-->
            <div>hello2</div>
```

Only hello2 shows. If you don't type in the dashes at the end:

```
        <div>hello3</div>
        <!-- COMMENT --------------- -->
        <div>hello4</div>
```

then both hello3 and hello4 are printed. Now, is there a way for me to make this work how it is suppposed to without going through the whole site and changing all the comments?
BTW it shows fine in all browsers, including firefox 4 and even IE. The problem only occurs on FF 3.6

Comment: I understand that what you have SHOULD work, however you should learn to not use a character that is comment syntax specific, like your '-', to apply spacing and formatting to your comments. Instead use a character like '#' or something.

Comment: Can you please define what you goal is?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The comment is started and finished by the sequence `--`.

```
<!-- COMMENT --------------- //-->
```

means:

- start comment
- space
- COMMENT
- space
- end comment
- start comment
- end comment
- start comment
- end comment
- start comment
- end comment
- dash space slash slash (outside a comment!)
- start comment

There is a reason that [the HTML specification says](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.4):

> A common error is to include a string of hyphens ("---") within a comment. Authors should avoid putting two or more adjacent hyphens inside comments.

---

> Now, is there a way for me to make this work how it is suppposed to without going through the whole site and changing all the comments?

No.

> BTW it shows fine in all browsers, including firefox 4 and even IE. The problem only occurs on FF 3.6

Too many bad authors depending on bugs in how some browsers mishandled comments meant that browser vendors have given up trying to implement comments correctly.

Mozilla didn't give up until after Firefox 3.6

Comment: A really fun aspect of this is trying to print debugging info into HTML comments, or commenting out the results of user-generated markup. You have to run a special escaping function over the text to make sure it doesn't contain -- pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Such usage of dashes in HTML comments causes unpredictable behaviour. See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2749 for more information about differences in HTML comments parsing. (Source of http://www.hixie.ch/tests/evil/mixed/comments-evil.html is very good example)

I recommend using some server script or Find&Replace feature in your text editor to replace dashes in comments with equals signs or another symbol.